# dynamic inline silverlight from string without files

Tags: silverlight, asp.net-mvc-2

for my final project in university i am developing in asp.net mvc3 and using silverlight for vector graphics.

I store silverlight code as string/xml in a database, and i want the ability to manipulate it dynamically (change proportions etc..) and display it in my aspx view. i don't want and can't use files because of scalability issues (there will be a lot of them) and because of possible porting of the application to the cloud (Azure).

basically i want to build a controller that will take raw xaml code from the DB and display it. all the solutions i found on the web are about two options which is not helpful for me:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189044(VS.95).aspx - which involves manually creating the entire dom object and integrating it in  an existing silverlight page, which i don't have
- http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2008/01/21/using-inline-xaml-with-silverlight-listing-2.aspx - using embedded header in the html itself - again not pracrtical..

maybe someone can suggest me a practical solution for my problem

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the you spend sometime examining in detail how the Silverlight navigation framework can be used.

I'm think you should be able to use the `Frame` element with your own implementation of `INavigationContentLoader` assigned to its `ContentLoader` property and possibly your own derivative to `UriMapperBase` assigned to its `UriMapper` property.

You would then use a URL like this:-

```
 http://yoursite.com/yourHostController#/yourXamlController/someReference
```

You would have two views, "yourHost" would simply generate the HTML nececessary to host the Silverlight application you will build.  The "yourXaml" view would simply serve up the raw Xaml.

Your Uri mapper will take the relative url supplied after the # (this is how silverlight intra-application navigation works) and create a Uri that can points at yourXaml controller.

Your implementation of `INavigationContentLoader` will then fetch the Xaml from the Uri and load it up.

Assuming the Xaml contains hyperlinks to using urls like "/yourXamlController/otherReference".  You should be able to navigate around your stored Xaml without reloading the Silverlight app.  Everything will be about referencing and downloading new chunks of Xaml.